# window.setInterval using local function

Tags: javascript, scope

I'm using `window.setInterval`, and it must have to be able to access a method that is defined in a "class", but since `setInterval` is in a scope separate from the method it was defined in, `this` resolves to `window` instead of the desired instance of `Game`. What code can I use to get the desired behaviour of calling `Game.update` instead of `window.update`?

(That looks kind of confusing. Maybe the following incorrect code can clear things up a bit.)

```
game = function () {
    /* ... */
    this.update = function () {
        /* ... */
    }
    this.interval = window.setInterval(this.update /* !!! */, 50);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done without a JS framework.

```
var game = function() {
  this.update = function() { }
  var that = this;
  setInterval(function() {
    that.update.apply(that);
  },50);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to Bind the method to the object.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind for an example of usage, and a drop-in script to bring bind() support to older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `this` keyword. its not available in `setInterval`. The following code should work.

```
game = function () {
    /* ... */
    this.update = function () {
        /* ... */
    var that = this  // add this line and use that instead of this in setInterval function
    }
    this.interval = window.setInterval(that.update /* !!! */, 50);
}
```